# InflateException DatePicker

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, inflate-exception

I am trying to show a DatePickerDialog in my Fragment when the user clicks an edittext

```
//initialise
Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

            etDate.setText(day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
        }

    },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

//show on click
datePickerDialog.show();
```

The problem is that is ends up with:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: tvfriends.kolio.com.tvproba, PID: 26562
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.widget.DatePicker
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.widget.DatePicker
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:119)
at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:90)
at tvfriends.kolio.com.tvproba.activities.HostActivity$DatePickerFragment.onCreateDialog(HostActivity.java:311)
at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:307)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1671)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:532)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable android:color/tab_indicator_text with resource ID #0x1060009
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/tab_indicator_text.xml from drawable resource ID #0x1060009
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:725)
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:854)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:924)
at android.widget.DatePickerCalendarDelegate.<init>(DatePickerCalendarDelegate.java:155)
at android.widget.DatePicker.createCalendarUIDelegate(DatePicker.java:143)
at android.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:123)
at android.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:109)
at android.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:105)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:119)
at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:90)
07-28 10:39:55.253 26562-26562/tvfriends.kolio.com.tvproba E/AndroidRuntime:     at tvfriends.kolio.com.tvproba.activities.HostActivity$DatePickerFragment.onCreateDialog(HostActivity.java:311)
at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:307)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1671)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:532)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #18: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:183)
at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:116)
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXml(DrawableInflater.java:130)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1224)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1197)
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:715)
... 34 more
```

I tried to make the DatePickerDialog a separate class but it is showing the a similar/same error.

Initialisation of the edittext that should trigger the datepicker:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.host_activity, container, false);

    View footer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_host, container, false);


    init(view, footer);




    return view;
}


private void init(View view, View footer) {
    etDate = (EditText) footer.findViewById(R.id.etDate);
    etDate.setOnClickListener(this);
    ....
}
```

Comment: show your xml code?

Comment: I don't have datepicker in my xml. I am using scrollview and without the code above everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use third party lib.because in native datepicker have some bug you face in some API.

```
  compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.4.0'
```

you can use it like below :

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            int  byear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int bmonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int bday = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.date.DatePickerDialog dialog= com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.date.DatePickerDialog.newInstance(new com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.date.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.date.DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    etDob.setText(new StringBuilder().append(dayOfMonth)
                            .append("/").append(monthOfYear + 1).append("/").append(year));
                    if (etDob.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                        etDob.setError("select Date");

                    } else {
                        etDob.setError(null);

                    }
                }
            }, byear, bmonth, bday);
            dialog.setMaxDate(cal);
            dialog.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(),"DatePicker");
```

if you not want to use 3rd party lib. then you can achieve like below.:

```
    private void setOnDateSet() {
    date = new DatePickerFragment();
    ondate = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int myear, int monthOfYear,
                              int dayOfMonth) {


            etDob.setText(new StringBuilder().append(dayOfMonth)
                    .append("/").append(monthOfYear + 1).append("/").append(myear));
            if (etDob.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                etDob.setError("select Date");

            } else {
                etDob.setError(null);

            }

        }

    };
}


public class DatePickerFragment extends android.app.DialogFragment {
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener ondateSet;
    int byear, bmonth, bday;


    public DatePickerFragment() {
    }

    public void setCallBack(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener ondate) {
        ondateSet = ondate;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        byear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        bmonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        bday = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


        DatePickerDialog _date = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), ondateSet, byear, bmonth, bday);
        _date.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
        return _date;
    }


}
```

And you can call it like below on edittext click listner:

```
       setOnDateSet(); // **** Set date on Button text
           date.setCallBack(ondate);
           date.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
```

Define this publicly :

```
  private DatePickerFragment date;


 private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener ondate;
```

Comment: Ok. It stopped showing this error but I guess I will find another third party lib to use.

Comment: Ok. I have tried several third parties and they work but when I try the built-in lib I get the same error. I will add initialisation of the edittext above. And yes - It is bind to an edittext.

Comment: Could the problem be that it is in the footer of a listview?